# Доказывание выпуклости многоугольника

Tags: математика

Что бы доказать выпуклость многоугольника, по общему мнению, надо применить псевдоскалярное умножение векторов. Применяя поочередно последовательно, по, или против часовой стрелки к углам многоугольника этот метод , мы получим некоторое значение со знаком плюс, или минус. Если знак для всех углов одинаков, то многоугольник выпуклый. Для доказывания выпуклости в системе координат предлагается формула , х1у2-х2у1 . И, надо полагать, в формуле представлены концы векторов, поскольку координаты всего две. Если векторы это стороны многоугольника, то где начало и где считать конец вектора? Например, имеем квадрат(многоугольник) ABCD. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если обходим по часовой стрелке, то сначала делаем вычисления , например, для точки A, потом B, потом С, и, наконец ,D. Для точки А вектора будут AD и AB, соответственно. И координаты , для выражения Х1У2-Х2У1, будут, соответственно, не начала, а концы векторов: Х1,У1 это точка D, а Х2,У2, точка В? Практическое вычисление показало, что у двух соседних углов знак разный.

Получен комментарий.

1 - Это вектора. 2 - вы их сами разворачиваете и потом удивляетесь. Сравнивайте DA и AB, а не AD и AB, и все будет как надо. – Kromster

Из комментария следует, что конец одного вектора есть начало другого. Но у нас всего 2 координаты? Что в этом случае х1.у1 и х2.у2?

Comment: Название вопроса не соответствует телу. Да и цитата черезчур избыточна. Метка Java тоже ни к селу, ни к городу .. В чем конкретно ваш вопрос, в том что такое вектор? У вектора нет "начала и конца", у него есть "направление". Если вам так удобнее, то начало вектора это 0:0, а конец - "направление".

Comment: У вектора нет начала, есть только координаты (на плоскости - две координаты: x и y в декартовой системе или направление и длина в полярной системе). Координаты считаются от начала вектора, само начало "нигде" не находится. Поэтому вектор можно как угодно перемещать по плоскости/в пространстве, и вектор при этом останется одним и тем же. Вектор - это не отрезок. (но отрезок можно задать двумя векторами)

Comment: Есть другое мнение  "Векторы в пространстве определяются так же, как и на плоскости. Это направленные отрезки, имеющие начало и конец. Отсюда и вопрос, собственно. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Мнение может быть каким угодно, но общепринятый подход вам уже изложили )

Comment: @JackSanders начало у вектора есть, но у начала нет координат. Координаты есть только у конца, и они отсчитываются относительно начала вектора.

Comment: Мне могли изложить, что батоны растут на деревьях. И, возможно, это действительно так. Но это надо доказать. Или хотя бы привести ссылку.  Все эти ваши менторские замашки, на самом деле , мимо тазика. Вопрос был не в этом. А в том, что есть х1,у1, х2, у2. Для двух векторов в системе координат.

Comment: Если бы вопрос был задан нормально, было бы смысл тратить время на разжевывание. А так .. помогли чем смогли )

Comment: Ответ, скорее всего, найден. И звучит так. "Координатами вектора являются координаты конечной точки этого вектора, если вектор расположен так, что его начало находится в начале координат. Если вектор находится на координатной плоскости, то каждая координата вектора равна разности соответствующих координат его конца и начала."

Comment: Если заменить 'координаты вектора' на 'компоненты вектора', то будет звучать нормально

Comment: @JackSanders "Ответ, скорее всего, найден. И звучит так." - вектор вообще не находится на вашей плоскости, он находится в своем "пространстве векторов". Вот есть скорость автомобиля, и она - это вектор, она где находится, в какой точке пространства? Или в какой точке автомобиля? Во всех точках автомобиля? Ответ - нигде в физическом пространстве. Можно представить, что есть воображаемое пространство векторов скоростей, где каждый вектор - это по сути точка в этом пространстве. Поэтому бессмысленно говорить о координатах начала вектора в физическом пространстве.

Comment: В физическом пространстве (в нашей мысленной модели физического пространства) "находятся" только радиус векторы, представляющие собой координаты точек в этом пространстве (каждый вектор как бы "исходит" из начала координат к каждой точке).

Comment: Еще вот пример вектора в одномерном пространстве. Пространство - линия времени, в которой каждая точка - это дата и врема. Промежуток между двумя моментами (точками) времени - это вектор. Вот промежуток времени (вектор) +5 секунд он где находится, в каком моменте времени? Ответ - нигде, это просто промежуток времени, куда нам нужно, туда и можем его приложить, но сам по себе он ни в каком моменте времени не находится.

Comment: @JackSanders Если бы Вы внимательнее прочитали текст по Вами же приведенной ссылке, то могли бы  увидеть, что это не разные точки зрения, а разные вектора:  фиксированные вектора, для определения которых нужно задавать координаты начала и конца, и свободные, у которых есть только координаты конца (условно, начало находится в точке с координатами (0, 0))

Answer (score 2):

Пусть имеется массив/список `A[]` из `N` вершин.

Входящий в `k`-ю вершину вектор - это разность координат вершин

```
Vin = A[k]-A[k-1]
```

его компоненты

```
Vin.X = A[k].X-A[k-1].X
Vin.Y = A[k].Y-A[k-1].Y
```

исходящий вектор

```
Vout = A[k+1]-A[k]
```

Кросс-продукт (псевдоскалярное умножение):

```
 CP = Vin x VOut = Vin.X * VOut.Y - Vin.Y * VOut.X
```

Чтобы не считать разности по два раза, после вычисления кросс-продукта копируем `Vout` в `Vin`, а перед первым шагом считаем `Vin = A[0]-A[n-1]`

Так будет понятнее?

Comment: Ваш вариант, чувствую интуитивно, верный, но мне не понятный. Верный ответ нашел сам. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Даны три точки *A*, *B*, *C*. Будем говорить (это определение) что угол *∠ABC* левый если соответствующий определитель больше нуля:

> ```
> | Ax Ay 1 |
> | Bx By 1 | > 0
> | Cx Cy 1 |
> ```

Этот определитель равен: *(A<sub>x</sub>B<sub>y</sub> - B<sub>x</sub>A<sub>y</sub>) + (B<sub>x</sub>C<sub>y</sub> - C<sub>x</sub>B<sub>y</sub>) + (C<sub>x</sub>A<sub>y</sub> - A<sub>x</sub>C<sub>y</sub>)*. Пары произведений забраны в скобки чтобы была видна циклическая перестановка *A→B→C→A...*.

Выражение можно переписать в виде *(B<sub>x</sub> - A<sub>x</sub>)(C<sub>y</sub> - B<sub>y</sub>) - (C<sub>x</sub> - B<sub>x</sub>)(B<sub>y</sub> - A<sub>y</sub>)*. Если вы раскроете скобки и сократите подобные, получите предыдущее выражение.

Введем обозначения для разности точек (вектора из *A* в *B*): *AB = B - A*, *AB<sub>x</sub> = B<sub>x</sub> - A<sub>x</sub>*, *AB<sub>y</sub> = B<sub>y</sub> - A<sub>y</sub>*. Обратите на обратный порядок в разнице.

Тогда последнее выражение можно переписать как *AB<sub>x</sub>BC<sub>y</sub> - BC<sub>x</sub>AB<sub>y</sub>*.

Последнее выражение называют [косым произведением векторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) *AB⋁BC* ( *= (B - A)⋁(C - B)*).

Это, кстати, тоже определитель:

> ```
> | ABx ABy|
> | BCx BCy| > 0
> ```

Возвращаясь к исходному вопросу. Вектора будут такие: *AB* и *BC*, *BC* и *CD*, *CD* и *DA*, *DA* и *AB*. Снова циклическая перестановка *A→B→C→D→A...*. А можно не думать о векторах, а говорить в терминах точек: *ABC*, *BCD*, *CDA*, *DAB*.